# JQuery UI ButtonSet Tooltips

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there any standard approach to add tooltip for each radiobutton in buttonset?

```
<span id="tools">
    <input type="radio" id="feature1" name="tool" title="feature 1"><label for="feature1">Tool 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="feature2" name="tool" title="feature 2"><label for="feature2">Tool 2</label>
</span>
```

and script:

```
$('#tools').buttonset();
```

I've already added title for each input but there are no any tooltips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
$(function() {
    ​$('label').each(function() {
        var radio = $(this).prop('for')​​​​​​​​;
        $(this).prop('title',$('#' + radio).prop('title'));
    });
});
```

​
All that it relies on is jQuery and the for attribute for each label is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply move the title attribute to the label.

Comment: And wrap the label around the radio buttons